# Is "as" the correct conjunction?

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Is "as" the correct conjunction to use here?

A cab pulls up. Jimmy gets in the passenger seat.

Cab driver: Hi.

Jimmy: Hi.

**As** they drive off --

Cab driver: Where to?

Comment: yes, it's ok. What are your doubts?

Comment: Didn't know if it should be 'as', 'when', or 'while'.

Comment: I would say 'as' is the best. 'While' not bad. 'When' not incorrect, but has a weaker connotation of duration (during).

Comment: The reality would be *before* they drive off.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not if Jimmy got in at a traffic light, for example. In any case, it's irrelevant to the question.